# Slow Ubuntu 20 compared to Ubuntu 16

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

I upgraded from Ubuntu 16 to 20 last night and now everything is running slowly and the cursor is laggy and unresponsive. I have an old HP Pavilion Entertainment PC.

Can I or should I revert to 16? I am not "tech savvy".

Comment: Please show the output of `top` and `free` in your question.

Comment: Either way, even if you managed to (e.g. using a backup), reverting to Ubuntu 16.04 at this point in time is *not* a good idea. That release reaches its End of Standard Support in April 2021.

Comment: Ubuntu has both releases that use the *yy* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 16), and use the *yy.mm* format (eg. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). They are different products, and you refer to the 16 & 20 in your question (ie. *snap* only specialist products) but have tagged a *deb* based 20.04 in tags?  Please clarify.  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS reaches the end of it's *standard* or public support next month, and has no upgrade path direct to 20.04 so your issues may have been self-introduced if you went outside of supported upgrade paths, or do you mean Ubuntu Core 16?  Please clarify.